# Custom CSS won't work in WP?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to do a slight change on a WP theme, I can't find the exact place to put in CSS and make it functional as I have test the same CSS code on FireBug's CSS Tab and it worked fine.

I have tried putting in style.css and also in Custom CSS which the theme offers but no effect. Thoughts?

This is my **CSS** and I am sure it is correct:

```
.top-links ul li {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: How are you linking this CSS? By any chance are you using `@import`? Can you link to your WP so we can take a look?

Comment: No I not using any `@import`. I am just appending this code into style.css file. This is site: 
https://www.frugobee.com/
I am applying CSS for the header, as you see there top right buttons are not clickable and needs to be z-indexed.

Comment: By any chance is your CSS file this one: `http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/287d598f62/UntitledProject1/style.css`?

Comment: Exactly - maybe you've made a typo in your CSS path?

Comment: I haven't use CSS path for linking, rather I have append this CSS code to exisitng style.css file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58080/discussion-between-eithedog-and-faisal-ashfaq).

Comment: Please come in chat for a moment.

Answer (score 2):

Please use fire bug / source view to find the css path that attached with your theme. In common wordpress layouts that is loaded under your theme folder and may be the file name is styles.css. If that is not working properly please use the css like this.

```
.top-links ul li {
position: relative!important;
z-index: 1!important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to [clear your browser's cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache)?